# Padding Jade template variable to inline function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, jscharts

I'm trying to use `JSCharts`.

```
block content
| <div id="chartcontainer">This is just a replacement in case Javascript is not available or used for SEO purposes</div>

script.
    var myData=new Array()
    var myData = new Array([10, 20], [15, 10], [20, 30], [25, 10], [30, 5]);
    var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer', 'line');
    myChart.setDataArray(myData);
    myChart.draw();
```

I created an array dynamically in nodejs

`[ [10, 20], [15, 10], [20, 30], [25, 10], [30, 5] ]`

and then passed it to jade.

`res.render('chart',{newArray:array});`

However, I'm unable to use it in the inline function mentioned above.

I tried using `var myData="#{newArray}"` but it just gives out a single string like `10,20,15,10,20,30...` which is unusable.

I also tried sending Json object. But it was also unusable after `"#{myJson}"` and/or `stringify`

What can I do? Also, is there any way I can use this script outside `script.` block? Because it wasn't able to find `JSChart()` when I tried that even though I have included the file in `head`. If that is possible then I can iterate the json and do something.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm using this solution:

```
block content
| <div id="chartcontainer">This is just a replacement in case Javascript is not available or used for SEO purposes</div>

-var myJson=JSON.stringify(json);
script.
    var array = new Array();
    var myData=JSON.parse(("#{myJson}").replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
    myData.forEach(function(data)
    {
        array.push([data.x,data.y]);
    })
    var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer', 'line');
    myChart.setDataArray(array);
    myChart.draw();
```

But it seems really stupid and unnecessary processing; Creating json in node and then sending it to jade, converting json to string and the again json and then array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unescaped String Interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) in JADE within script tags.

Simply use the `!{}` tags.

```
var array = new Array(!{newArray})
```

Should work fine

Comment: No, it still gives array of length 1
`[10,20,15,10,20,30...]`even though I'm sending: `[[10,20] , [15,10], [20,30] ]`

Comment: Then in your server side code, send the string as JSON `{newArray: JSON.stringify(array)}` and in the client side, `array = !{JSON.parse(newArray)}` should do the trick